# Relative permiability vs B curve characteristics

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Recently while reading a book I came across this graph. [image: graph of relative permeability versus flux density]

The book just explains why B is better than NI. Nothing about the actual characteristics of the curve.
The initial increase can be understood by assuming that the domains are lining up as B is increased (i think?), but what about the later part? Why the drop?

Any explination will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since $B=\mu_0 (H + M)$ if you plot the static $\mu_0 \mu_{r}=B/H$ for high enough magnetizing force $H$ you eventually align *all* domains in which case $M=M_{max}$ a material constant and $M/H \to 0$ as $H \to \infty $ and thus $\mu_{r} \to 1$, that is the downward end of the curve on the right.

In practice, the *static* permeability is not really meaningful nor useful for a ferromagnet, instead a *differential* permeability is defined, i.e., $\mu_d = \frac{1}{\mu_0}\frac{dB}{dH}$ and not the simple ratio $\mu_{r} =\frac{B}{\mu_0H}$. The $\mu_d$ is meaningful and a directly measurable quantity using a.c. excitation and Faraday's law of induction around a fixed "operating point $I_0$", say with current $I(t)=I_0+I_1cos(\omega t)$ and consequently a magnetizing force $H(t)=H_0+H_1cos(\omega t)$ where $\omega$ is the a.c. frequency and $H_1 << H_0$ is its *small* oscillation amplitude around the operating point $H_0$. The $\mu_d(H_0)$ is the slope of the curve $\mu_r=\mu_r(H_0)$